# how to not reload a page after popup closes

Tags: javascript

I have a simple close function with a popup window but when I close the window it refreshes the parent page. I don't want the page to refresh and all I can find is code on how to refresh the page. So how do I get it to not refresh the parent page? I just have a simple button made to close the page.

```
function loading()
{
window.close();
}

<tr>
<td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Close" tabindex="3" id="closed" /></td>
<tr>
```

Comment: That is some invalid code...Also give no details on how you actually call it or how it works.

Comment: `return false` from the function (which I assume is `function loading(){` and not `function (loading){` which is a syntax error.

Comment: And @Mr.Alien did not read the question.

Comment: @epascarello my bad, I will retract that one

Answer (score 0):

Return false from your function.

Comment: This _might_ be it, but we need additional code to know. We don't know if this originated from an `onsubmit` handler?

Comment: That is true, but I suspect it is.  If it's a submit function, then he is screwed.